# Using filter with ProTable in Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using [ProTable](https://procomponents.ant.design/components/table) in Ant Design Pro. The dataSource for the table is received by API from the server. If the user is not an admin, I filter the dataSource by his `userid`. The problem is that I can't get the actual count of total pages for both cases (admin and user).

Here is the code for my API request function:

```
function getRule(req, res, u) {
  let realUrl = u;

  if (!realUrl || Object.prototype.toString.call(realUrl) !== '[object String]') {
    realUrl = req.url;
  }

  const { current = 1, pageSize = 5 } = req.query;
  const params = parse(realUrl, true).query;
  let dataSource = [...tableListDataSource].slice((current - 1) * pageSize, current * pageSize);
  const filter = JSON.parse(params.filter);

  if (filter) {
    if (Object.keys(filter).length > 0) {
      dataSource = tableListDataSource.filter((item) => {
        return Object.keys(filter).some((key) => {
          if (!filter[key]) {
            return true;
          }

          if (filter[key].includes(`${item[key]}`)) {
            return true;
          }

          return false;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  // TODO: Fix total count of pages for admin
  const total = () => {
    if (Object.keys(filter).length > 0) {
      return dataSource.length
    } else {
      return tableListDataSource.length
    }
  }

  const result = {
    data: dataSource,
    total: total,
    success: true,
    pageSize,
    current: parseInt(`${params.currentPage}`, 10) || 1,
  };
  return res.json(result);
}
```

But instead of `dataSource.length` for user and `tableListDataSource.length` for admin I get `dataSource.length` for both cases. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `total` should be an assignment, not a function:

```
const total = Object.keys(filter).length > 0 ? dataSource.length : tableListDataSource.length
```